# MS NAV 2016 RTC crashes after migration

Tags: crash, dynamics-nav-2016

i would like to share a simple solution to a strange problem.

We are using MS Dyncamics NAV 2016. After the migration from 2013 some users had experienced random RTC crashes.

We could narrow the problem to a Chart Part in the Rolecenter. Removing the chart as a user and restoring the defaults has apparently solved the problem.

I hope this helps someone.

Best regards

Here our only hint, the stack trace:

```
    Type: Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.UI.LogicalOperationAbortedException
Message: GetAggregates operation has been Canceled
StackTrace:
     bei Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.WinClient.ExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<DoRethrowWithCatchException>b__4()
     bei Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.WinClient.NavClientErrorHandler.ExecuteAndCatchExceptions(Func`1 execute)
     bei Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.WinClient.ExceptionHandler.DoExecute(Func`1 execute)
     bei Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.WinClient.ExceptionHandler.DoRethrowWithCatchException(Exception exception, Boolean designMode)
Source: Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.WinClient
HResult: -2146233088
----------------------------------
Type: Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.UI.LogicalOperationAbortedException
Message: GetAggregates operation has been Canceled
StackTrace:
     bei Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.UI.VisualizationControl.VisualizationLoadDataComplete(Object sender, LogicalTaskCompleteEventArgs e)
     bei Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.UI.VisualizationLoadDataTask.OnLoadDataComplete(Object sender, LogicalTaskCompleteEventArgs eventArgs)
     bei Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.UI.LogicalTask.OnTaskComplete(Object sender, LogicalTaskCompleteEventArgs eventArgs)
Source: Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.UI
HResult: -2146233088
----------------------------------
Type: Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.UI.LogicalOperationAbortedException
Message: GetAggregates operation has been Canceled
StackTrace:
     bei Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.UI.VisualizationLoadDataTask.LoadData()
     bei Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.UI.LogicalTaskRunner.ExecuteOperation(Func`2 operation, Object arg, Guid taskId)
Source: Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.UI
HResult: -2146233088
----------------------------------
Type: Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.UI.LogicalOperationCanceledException
Message: GetAggregates operation has been Canceled
StackTrace:
     bei Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.DataBinder.AggregatedTableDataReader.FillDataTableInternal(QueryOptions options, Guid taskId)
     bei Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.UI.TableDataReader.FillDataTable(QueryOptions options)
     bei Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.UI.AggregatedTableVisualizationLoadDataTask.LoadDataCore()
     bei Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.UI.VisualizationLoadDataTask.LoadData()
Source: Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.UI
HResult: -2146233088
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the chart as a user from the Rolecenter, restarting the client and restoring the default Parts on the Rolecenter has apparently solved the problem.